# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have the same code in three pages, but in two of them, this error occurs:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialised with a non-nil layout parameter

I don't understand why, if the code is the same in three pages and in the first page i don't have any problem.

My Code in header file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *marrImages;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableDictionary *mdictImageData;



@end
```

and in .m file

```
@interface CollectionViewController ()

@end

@implementation CollectionViewController


@synthesize marrImages,mdictImageData;

static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"cell";


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //navigation bar
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];
    UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
    [backButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(leftButtonAcion:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *button2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button2;
    self.title = @"Welcome";

    marrImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    mdictImageData=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"circlshadow_parking.png",@"imageFile",@"Estacionamentos",@"Info",nil];
    [marrImages addObject:mdictImageData];

   mdictImageData=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"circlshadow_charging.png",@"imageFile",@"Carregar Saldo",@"Info", nil];
    [marrImages addObject:mdictImageData];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [marrImages count];
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.lblIndex.text=[[marrImages objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]valueForKey:@"Info"];
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:[[marrImages objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]valueForKey:@"imageFile"]];
    [cell.ivCartoon setImage:image];
    return cell;
}


- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger lastIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition:[indexPath length] - 1];




    if(lastIndex == 0)
    {
        ParkingMenu *parkingMenu = [[ParkingMenu alloc] init];
        parkingMenu.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
        parkingMenu.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:parkingMenu animated:YES];
        [parkingMenu release];

    }
    else if(lastIndex == 1)
    {

        BalanceMenu *balanceMenu = [[BalanceMenu alloc] init];
        balanceMenu.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
        balanceMenu.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:balanceMenu animated:YES];
        [balanceMenu release];

    }
    else if(lastIndex == 2)
    {
    }
    else if(lastIndex == 3)
    {
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: How are these controller instances created (show code)?

Comment: I have my views in a storyboard. This is my first app , for which I am not much in the know. I need to instantiate somewhere is that with the former did not do it and everything is fine.

Comment: So it;s the parking and balance 'pages' that have a problem? And they are defined in the storyboard? How are they defined in the storyboard?

Comment: My storyboard: http://postimg.org/image/50natv1st/

Comment: and now? http://s30.postimg.org/srmobz201/Captura_de_Tela_2015_12_07_s_16_18_05.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
    ParkingMenu *parkingMenu = [[ParkingMenu alloc] init];
    parkingMenu.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
    parkingMenu.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:parkingMenu animated:YES];
    [parkingMenu release];
```

shows that you're creating an instance of `ParkingMenu` without referencing the storyboard. Presumably this is a subclass of `UICollectionViewController` and is resulting in you not using the designated initialiser `initWithCollectionViewLayout:` or unarchiving from the storyboard (which would also set the layout).

You're also not using ARC, so you have to call `release`, which you shouldn't do really...

You need to update your code so it triggers a segue between the view controllers or so it loads the `ParkingMenu` from the storyboard by identifier.

Comment: That depends on what's in the storyboard. Can't see your image as it's blocked here...

Comment: I resolve the problem with this UIStoryboard * mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ParkingMenu"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];  but the navigation bar dissapears on the two next pages

Comment: this is the by identifier approach (as opposed to a segue)

Comment: I did not understand what you mean. sorry

Comment: In my answer 1 listed 2 potential solutions, that code is the second of them, just for your information